# How to get the same length to display alphanumeric keys ?

Tags: css

I want to display the alphanumeric keys with the same length. I used text-align:center and text-align:justify. But i get different length for each keys. It doesn't look good in my UI. Help me to solve this.

Eg.

- d60cfd74dfe8werersd3343sd464b6b6e2b0
- 31f32ef2e3f233aa8b5d864cd73f0ceed0df
- e3aa0a5asdfdsafasdfsawerbab409816a62
- f9b33535dsfadasdfsaf1331313fsfsgga87
- 1b65ed504werewrewwerewr1212112rw584c

Comment: Inside li place a div and then place your data.Given text align:justify for both li and div.It will work

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple same length strings to show the same display length, then you need to use a fixed spacing font such as `font-family: "Courier New"` or something like that.  With a proportional font, the width of the string on the screen will vary according to which characters are in the string.  With a fixed width font, each character is the same width so equal length strings will display the same length.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wCWWA/

Comment: Now its looking fine. Thanks :)